# Get the last value of property in table using LINQ asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I want to get the value if a number is inserted into database. I've used the Last function but it didn't work and returned error:

> last not defined by LINQ TO ENTITIES.

This is the code I've used :

```
int  NumD = LigneCommande.Last().NumDocument;
```

This is my class LigneCommande :

```
public partial class LigneCommande
{


    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int NumDocument { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int NumLigne { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string CodeArticle { get; set; }

    public int Quantite { get; set; }

    public int Disponible { get; set; }

    public decimal PrixUnitaire { get; set; }

    public byte Existe { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Designation { get; set; }

    public byte Commander { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Nature { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateDisponibilite { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string commentaire { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string numFacture { get; set; }

    public decimal? Remise { get; set; }

    public decimal? QteANNULEE { get; set; }

    public int? statusAnnulee { get; set; }

    [Column("Relicat Qte")]
    public decimal? Relicat_Qte { get; set; }
}
```

I tried to changed `Last()`with `First()` just for testing and it works fine. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There really isn't a concept of "last" in an open-ended data source.  For example, note that in SQL there is no syntax for taking the `BOTTOM 1` record, just the `TOP 1`.

But "first" works just as well if you sort descending.  Something like this:

```
int NumD = LigneCommande.OrderByDescending(l => l.SomeProperty).First().NumDocument;
```

That would give you the "last" object by ordering them in reverse order and taking the "first".  All you need to do is define what that order is.

Comment: when I try NumD =dbs. LigneCommande.First().NumDocument it works , but when I try :                                                                                                      int NumD = dbs.LigneCommande.OrderByDescending(l => l.SomeProperty).First().NumDocument; I get this error :             Unable to use context when creating the model

Comment: @Sarra: Are you sure that's the error message?  Google seems to suggest that you're the only person who has ever received that error...

Comment: it is work now , thank you for you help :) :)  @David your solution work , thanks

Answer (score 1):

no one would be able to answer this unless we knew what `LigneCommande` was defined as.  The only way that I could see this code working is id `LigneCommande` was some type of `IEnumerable<int>` or `int[]` which it is probably not since you said this is comming for the database. What you probably want is something like this:

```
   int  NumD = LigneCommande.Select(x => x.MyColumnNameThatIsAInt).LastOrDefault();
```

Answer (score -1):

int  NumD = LigneCommande.AsEnumerable().LastOrDefault();

Comment: when I try NumD = dbs.igneCommande.First().NumDocument it works , but when I try :